# Intel AMT 2.0 PowerUp/PowerDown Issue RemoteControlService/Interface

Tags: intel

I am trying to turn off my Intel AMT 2.0 Blade through RemoteControlService.wsdl but It only exposes one method that is newOpereation. Help provided on software.intel is out dated i.e is of 2006.

When I turn off my Intel AMT 2.0 Blade using http://192.168.3.115:16992 It successfully turn it off but could not turn it on because it stops reply ping request.

Is there any issue with my AMT 2.0 Blade?

Can any body share code of Java using RemoteControlService.wsdl. I used in in .Net but we can not install .net platform just to run an exe.

Using BIOS Version 5773

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to fix provisioning settings for your AMT Blade. go to the following document

http://software.intel.com/file/42139 [Goto page 3 bottom]

further more you need an AMT.jar file if you want to use in a programmable way.